# SwiftUi is there a way to get a Text inside a TextField

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-text

I have recently migrated from UIKit to SwiftUi 2.0 and I am rebuilding my app with SwiftUI . In UIKit I have a textbox and inside that textbox I have a post button and I am trying to do the same in SwiftUi but have not succeeded . In the image below for SwiftUi you can see that the Text is outside the TextField . This is the code I have for that region

```
      HStack {
                TextField("", text: $Postdata)
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    .frame(height: 38)
                        Text("Post")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .padding(.trailing, 10)
                    }
```

This is how it looks in UIKit

[image]

This is how I have it in SwiftUI, as you can see the post text is outside the TextField, any suggestions would be great

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ZStack`, we  can arrange view in z axis.
Spacer() is also doesn't block any view taping, dragging and etcetera   like `EmptyView()`. It only provide space as the name itself.

```swift
 struct ContentView: View {
        @State var postdata = ""
        var body: some View {
            ZStack {
                TextField("", text: $postdata)
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    .frame(height: 38)
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Button(action: {
                        
                    }, label: {
                        Text("Post")
                            .bold()
                            .foregroundColor(.green)
                            .padding(.trailing, 10)
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
```